# Retrieve SQL value in Airflow

Tags: python, sql, airflow

I have to retrieve SQL value, and check if that is 0 in Airflow. Below is my sample snippet:

```
check_phase = BashOperator(
       task_id='check_phase',
       bash_command='python3 /path to run_sql.py -e dev /path to sql/run_sql.sql  (i),
    dag=dag,
)
```

Variable called `res` is there in `run_sql.py`.Now I have to get that value and check if that value is 0 or not and implement mailing in another Task based on the `res` value. I checked in Xcom, but the value was none. How to proceed..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want last line written to stdout will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes you need to set `do_xcom_push=True` as:

```
check_phase = BashOperator(
       task_id='check_phase',
       bash_command='python3 /path to run_sql.py -e dev /path to sql/run_sql.sql  (i)',
       do_xcom_push=True,
       dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: I  did  but its returning value as none

Comment: probably a local issue with your code. If you share a reproduce example I can help further.

Comment: mail  = BashOperator(
              task_id='mail',
             bash_command='echo "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="check_phase",key="return_value") }}"',
                             dag=dag,
)